# "message": "invalid token" when I use bearer jwt token

Tags: express, jwt

[image: I use this tipe of duthorization header]

I use this type of authorization header in postman;
And in my middleware I have the following code:

```
    try {
        jwtPayload = <any>jwt.verify(<string>req.headers["authorization"], config.jwtSecret);
        res.locals.jwtPayload = jwtPayload;
    } catch (error) {
        //If token is not valid, respond with 401 (unauthorized)
        res.status(401).send(error);
        return;
    }
```

```
console.log(req.headers["authorization"]) = Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgxMTg3Nzg2LCJleHAiOjE1ODExOTEzODZ9.FzZjk-X5AsWP43BFLA3QU1Qd3G9z6NJBT8bdASLzei4
```

and I get this message when I try to access route with middleware:

```
{
    "name": "JsonWebTokenError",
    "message": "invalid token"
}
```

when I use only token (eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgxMTg3Nzg2LCJleHAiOjE1ODExOTEzODZ9.FzZjk-X5AsWP43BFLA3QU1Qd3G9z6NJBT8bdASLzei4) middleware is passed succesfully;
my question is, should I remove Bearer from request or to sent header without Bearer?

Comment: You can continue to send it as Bearer token, but in your auth middleware you need to extract the token, and use it in the jwt.verify. `jwt.verify(<string>req.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1], config.jwtSecret)`

Comment: I did this jwtPayload = <any>jwt.verify(token.substring(7), config.jwtSecret); but I think your way is better

Comment: They do the same thing:) you can use one of them.

Comment: You can add an answer yourself so that others don't spend on this.

Answer (score 0):

I used `<any>jwt.verify(token.substring(7), config.jwtSecret)` to get only token